# Why is moment.js subtracting 4 hours from a date time item coming from SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm using moment to properly configure my datetime item coming from SharePoint.

For example, here's how the date looks like with no conversion coming from a API call on a SP list: `/Date(1657281600000)/`

So using moment, I do the following:

```
myRealDateTime = moment(myDateTime[i].start).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a')
```

My result gives me the correct date, but for some reason it's subtracting 4 hours from my time.

How can I fix this? Should I be using moment-timezone?

Comment: Probably because of the time zone that SharePoint is configured to is 4 hours different than your local time zone.

Comment: when I check the XML endPoint of the list the time is correct. In the sharepoint list itself, the time is correct. When I pull that date time from sharepoint, moment adds 4 hours. Also, the SharePoint server is local, it's literally in the same building 2 floors above me.

Comment: The time in the endpoint is, 2022-06-28T08:00:00. When it goes through moment. I  get 06/28/2022 04:00 am